# Multiple concurrent instances of the ASP.net page to be treated separately

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, multiple-instances

I'm new to ASP.net. I've got an ASP.net application which updates data in Dynamics CRM, on the click of the button on the ASP.net page. When single instance of the application is running it's working as expected and updating the relevant CRM record but when the application is opened in multiple tabs (concurrently) at the same time, the last submitted instance of the ASP.net page is the only instance that's updating the data in CRM but again with the data of the first instance of the page. We are making use of the ViewState variables to pass the data to the server on post back.

What should I be doing to treat each instance the same ASP.net page as separate independent instance (when run concurrently) and update the relevant record in the CRM without cross-interference. Basically, treat each process instance as a separate instance.

Comment: Did you also make use of Session? Or cookies?

Comment: Or static variables?

Comment: Just a Viewstate variable which contains a list of custom datatype.

Comment: Well, please produce a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

The application was initiated (multiple processes) so quickly even before the garbage collector cleaned up the memory for the previous instances of the same program. Disposing of the variables / resources in the finally block fixed the problem.